# Java: YAML file handling

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I am using snakeyaml to handle a yaml config file in Java.

My YAML file structure is this:

config.yml

```
User1: "John Doe"
User2: "Jane Smith"
User3: "James Doe"
```

When I do:

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
data.put("KR", "test");
String output = yaml.dump(data);
FileWriter f = new FileWriter("config.yml");
f.write(output);
```

Nothing is written to the config file.

I want to write my key values to the `config.yml` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to be closing your [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html). You might need to specify the path as well,

```
FileWriter f = new FileWriter("c:/config.yml"); // for c:\\config.yml
f.write(output);
f.close();
```

Comment: thank you so much. That solved it. It was not specifying the path. I assumed it would look for it in the current dir without specification.